# Issue in implementing video calling?

Tags: iphone, ios

i have to implement video calling in my application. but don't  find anything related to that on google. please guide me if you have some knowledge regarding the video calling.

Can you suggest me, may i go for third party library or i should code the module by own. 
because i have  to capture the frame from camera & compress them then i have to live stream that frame to server then server to iphone using http live streaming. it may cause too much delay?

What can i do? i will go for third party api or may i code video calling.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this project: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

> PJSIP is a free and open source multimedia communication library
>   written in C language implementing standard based protocols such as
>   SIP, SDP, RTP, STUN, TURN, and ICE. It combines signaling protocol
>   (SIP) with rich multimedia framework and NAT traversal functionality
>   into high level API that is portable and suitable for almost any type
>   of systems ranging from desktops, embedded systems, to mobile
>   handsets.

PJSIP supports the SIP protocol:

> The Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) is an IETF-defined signaling
>   protocol widely used for controlling communication sessions such as
>   **voice and video calls** over Internet Protocol (IP). The protocol can be
>   used for creating, modifying and terminating two-party (unicast) or
>   multiparty (multicast) sessions. Sessions may consist of one or
>   several media streams.